# In C, how do I print out a character array then empty it after?

Tags: c, arrays, char, character

I am trying to read a file line per line and check if there are any labels, which are written in the form of "**label:**". It checks the existence of the semicolon and pretty much just appends the characters before the semicolon into a character array `temp`. Then, empties `temp` and using fgets function to read the next line.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
char temp[200] = "";

    while(fgets(line, len, fp) != NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == ' ') continue;
            else if(line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != ':')
            {
                append(temp, line[i]);
                continue;
            }
            else if (line[i] == ':')
            {
                printf("Scanned label %s\n", temp);
                char temp[200] = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

and `append` is a special function used to append individual characters to the character array `temp`

```
void append (char* str, char ch)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    str[len] = ch;
    str[len+1] = '\0';
}
```

In the four lines of the text file, there is one label for each line. Here's an example of the input file:

```
L1: this is a sentence
L2: this is another sentence
L3: this is another sentence
L4: this is the last sentence
```

I managed to get the output

```
Scanned label
Scanned label
Scanned label
Scanned label
```

But as you can see, I am unable to print out the contents of the character array `temp`. So, my question is that if there is anything that I can fix this or if there are any logical flaws with my code?

And as for the emptying the character array, is what I did right? By simply just:

```
char temp[200] = "";
```

Comment: You don't have to "empty" the array before using `fgets()` again. You should provide a [mcve] and sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't doing what you expect:

```
else if( ( line[i] != ' ' || line[i] == ':') && (line[i] == '\0'))
```

This condition will only be true if `line[i]` is the terminating null byte, so the only thing you'll append to the string is that.  You want to append if you get a non-space or  a non `:`.  You do that like this:

```
else if( ( line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != ':'))
```

Then there's this part:

```
        else if (line[i] == ':')
        {
            printf("Scanned label %s\n", temp);
            char temp[200] = "";
        }
```

The line reading `char temp[200] = "";` is *not* clearing `temp` defined at the top of the block, but is creating a **new** variable named `temp`.  This variable immediately goes out of scope, so it has no effect.  You would then continue to append to `temp` for each label, ending up with `"L1L2L3L4"`.

To make `temp` an empty string, just set the first element to 0:

```
        else if (line[i] == ':')
        {
            printf("Scanned label %s\n", temp);
            temp[0] = '\0';
            break;
        }
```

Note also that we `break` out of the inner loop so we can read the next line.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to "empty" the temp array.

> And as for the emptying the character array, is what I did right? By simply just: `char temp[200] = "";`

Just using `char temp[200];` at initialization is enough. The second declaration, within the if statement, is completely wrong. Just remove it.

Other remarks:

`(line[i] != ' ' || line[i] == ':')` will always evaluate to true. You should review this condition.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, thanks a lot! Can't believe I missed it. I have a question though, since you said that "there is no need to empty the temp array," does that mean appending a "\0" to the end of the character array would truncate it and leave the array empty? Or is that because I am reading a new line with the fgets() function like the other comment said?

Comment: Any previous `\0' will either be ignored or overwritten.